# update every elements replaceWith partial rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial

I have 3 elements and one form with a button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Follow All" class="follow_all">

<div id="page"> 
<div id="page01" class="pages"> page 1 </div>
<div id="page02" class="pages"> page 2 </div>
<div id="page03" class="pages"> page 3 </div>
</div>
```

When I click in submit button, the form action, call to the file **create.js.erb**.

In this file I have:

```
var $divs = ("#page .pages");
$($divs).replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'replace_all_divs'))%>");
```

In the partial **_replace_all_divs.html.erb** I have:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<%= post.id   %>
<% end %>
```

I want **replace** each **div content (page 1, page 2 and page 3)** with **post id**.

The problem is that I get for each div the 3 ids of post.id:

**I get a bad result :(:**

```
<div id="page"> 
<div id="page01" class="pages"> 123 </div>
<div id="page02" class="pages"> 123 </div>
<div id="page03" class="pages"> 123 </div>
</div>
```

I want get the next result:

```
<div id="page"> 
<div id="page01" class="pages"> 1 </div>
<div id="page02" class="pages"> 2 </div>
<div id="page03" class="pages"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using `"#page .pages"` as the selector, the `replaceWith` method is executed three times, each one with the content produced by **_replace_all_divs.html.erb** (a loop that concatenates all your ids => "123").

You'd better use `"#page"` as the selector and replace its **content** with new divs.

**create.js.erb** :

```
$('#page').empty().append('<%= render(:partial => 'replace_all_divs')%>');
```

**_replace_all_divs.html.erb** :

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <div id="page<%= post.id.to_s.rjust(2, '0') %>" class="pages"><%= post.id %></div>
<% end %>
```